# PHP & MySQL Distinct results using INNER JOIN, WHERE and OR clauses (filtering duplicates)

Tags: mysql, duplicates, distinct

I know the question is very old, but it's hard to run a very specific search and situations may still differ in little but crucial ways. I'm trying to figure out the correct mysql query for my forum search script. What I need is to list both topics and posts containing matching strings with a single query, both have to be supplied with respective results from another table (topics and posts). In case of any matches in the topic name there should be **only 1 post** per each topic, which is the very first one. My initial query thus:

```
SELECT topics.topic, posts.post 
FROM topics 
JOIN posts
ON 
posts.topic_id=topics.id 
WHERE topics.topic LIKE '%$search%'
OR posts.post LIKE '%$search%'
```

This will return all the posts with matching strings correctly but also a lot of duplicate topics along with as many irrelevant posts as the matching topic contains. Typically one should use GROUP BY in such situation, but it won't do any good here since grouping by either topics.topic or posts.post will be mutually detrimental. I also don't see how SELECT DISTINCT could help any and it doesn't seem to do anything anyway, and LIMIT 1 cannot be applied individually here. As always, my last resort is 2 individual queries, but if a single call is possible I would be very delighted to see it.

Comment: you should start to find a way to find these relevant topic, and then you can sort

Comment: Sorry I am struggling to understand what you want as a result set - can you supply some examples of data and desired results?

Comment: I know this is not exactly transparent, but basically: 1) If there is a match in a topic name - list both the topic name and the very first post made in that topic where the link between them is the topic id, 2) If there is a match in a post or posts - list it all along with the topic names 3) All these combinations should be listed INDIVIDUALLY regardless. It can't quite be done with the query provided above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT t.topic as tpost, ppost = (SELECT post.post FROM posts p WHERE p.topic_id = t.id ORDER BY posts.id LIMIT 1)
FROM topics t 
where topics.topic LIKE 'xxx'
union 
SELECT t2.topic, p2.post 
FROM posts p2
JOIN topics t2 on p2.topic_id = t2.id
WHERE posts.post LIKE 'xxx'
```

EDIT
Testing of this suggested solution proved a mod is required:

```
SELECT t.topic as tpost, (SELECT post.post FROM posts p WHERE p.topic_id = t.id ORDER BY posts.id LIMIT 1) as ppost
FROM topics t 
where topics.topic LIKE 'xxx'
union 
SELECT t2.topic, p2.post 
FROM posts p2
JOIN topics t2 on p2.topic_id = t2.id
WHERE posts.post LIKE 'xxx'
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry though, I don't really understand what this does. Could you break it down, please? I understand UNION and I'd thought of using it but given the situation it didn't seem trivial. I also suspected that there's no way I could do this without subqueries, which, frankly, I'm not very good at.

Comment: THE first SELECT searches the topic table for "topics.topic LIKE 'searchterm'" and just to fill the second column it finds the first post linked to the topic using the subquery (the post in the second column here does not necessarily contain the searchterm.) The second SELECT searches posts for "posts.post LIKE 'searchterm'" and brings in the parent topic to fill the first column - again this topic in the first column may not contain the search term. The UNION just joins the two sets of results into a single result set. Give it a go.

Comment: Yes, but... still failed to adapt it to my occasion. BUT! I think I have finally figured it out myself, check below for the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Ok everyone, the solution was lots more simple than expected (no sub-queries are necessary after all):

```
SELECT topics.topic, posts.post 
FROM topics 
JOIN posts ON posts.topic_id = topics.id 
WHERE topic LIKE '%$search%' 
GROUP BY topics.id 
UNION 
SELECT topics.topic, posts.post 
FROM posts
JOIN topics ON topics.id = posts.topic_id
WHERE posts.post LIKE '%$search%'
```

Of course, the SELECT order matters a lot and one little thing can change everything. Thank you all for help and let's hope this will assist others in the future!

Comment: While this might produce 'a' result for you, you have not defined which of the child posts will be selected in the first SELECT, and it might change from one call to the next, and from one database product to the next. You said you wanted "the very first post made in that topic" - your solution does not guarantee that. See my edited solution for a query that meets your requirements with no ambiguity.